# How to deal with downvotes on legitimate questions?

Tags: discussion, votes

A lot of questions are getting downvoted while being very interesting and legitimate questions. I don't know why this happens but I would like to know a way to deal with this since it really discourages (especially new users) to write questions.

For example [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56722/does-george-lucas-mention-earth-in-star-wars/56761#56761) question got downvoted and recieved a lot of negative comments in it's first hours of existance. If I was the guy who asked the question I would have believed that there is something wrong and I would have deleted my question.

Thing is that now it has 11.000 views 21 upvotes and 5 favourite stars.

Comment: Without an actual example this is way too broad an incredibly diffucult to answer reasonably. More often than not downvotes are a sign that there's something wrong with the question that should be worked on, but without knowing what question you talk about, we can't really pin down what. I have noticed that we had quite a few downvoted questions lately, but frankly, the questions seem to be rather sub-par to begin with.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Editing question with example

Comment: Well, that question was worded very poorly at first. But sure, editing or reverting the downvote after editing is preferrable. Then again, it's also something some users just deemed a useless question, however, once it hit the Hot Network Questions list, it naturally generates an overabundance of upvotes, which might not necessarily reflect how this community actually judges the question. Such the is the thing with votes, they just work in their own weird ways.

Comment: As a side note, please stop equating favourite stars to likes or anything positive. They are just bookmarks, and I bookmark a ton of bad questions every day.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I agree that stars are not likes. But stars mean interest for the question. For any reason.

Comment: Yes, including the reason that the question is crap that should be kept under surveillance. ;-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson haha ok!

Comment: @NapoleonWilson http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2583/does-batman-begins-occur-before-tim-burtons-batman is another example. This question is downvoted because of what? I think that people must give a justification when they downvote.  If they think that the batman movies are not related they should post an answer writing exactly this.